# Как вынести функцию из многопоточности?

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

У меня есть вот такой код

```
if os.path.exists(term2label_path):
    with open(term2label_path) as f:
        term2label = json.load(f)
else:
    term2label = {}

with multiprocessing.Pool(job_count) as pool:
        mined_jsons = pool.map(mine_pdf, ((p, for_train) for p in doc_paths))
        dataset_last_labeled_page = max(chain(
            [0],
            (page_index for _, page_index in mined_jsons if page_index)
        ))
        LOG.info(f'Last labeled page index in dataset is'
                 f' {dataset_last_labeled_page}')

        if for_train:
            pool.map(create_labeled_tokens,
                     ((path, term2label, dataset_last_labeled_page)
                      for path, last_labeled_page in mined_jsons
                      if last_labeled_page is not None))

            store_parents_children_to_model(parents_children_dir, model_dir)

        else:
            pool.map(create_text,
                     (path for path, last_labeled_page in mined_jsons))
```

В этом коде есть функция `create_labeled_tokens` Эта функция выполняется в режиме многопоточности.

Я хочу чтобы все функции выполнялись в режиме многопоточости, но `create_labeled_tokens` выполнялась в одном потоке.

Для общего понимания, результатом работы каждой из функций есть сохранение я дерикторию.

Как мне вынести эту функцию из многопточности?
Буду благодарен за любые советы
Спасибо

Comment: 1) тут вообще нет многопоточности:-) 2) А где строки с import?

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое - заменить `pool.map` на просто `map`, вернее на `list(map(...))`, потому что `map` делает генератор (`map` - это скорее аналог `pool.imap`), а он "ленивый", его нужно проитерировать, чтобы он выполнился:

```
        if for_train:
            list(map(create_labeled_tokens,
                     ((path, term2label, dataset_last_labeled_page)
                      for path, last_labeled_page in mined_jsons
                      if last_labeled_page is not None)))
```

По идее, будет всё тоже самое, только в одном процессе.

И, на всякий случай: мультипроцессность и многопоточность - это не одно и то же, хотя штуки и похожие, лучше их всё-таки уметь различать.

Answer (score 1):

Для вызова функции в асихронном режиме (выполнение в одном рабочем процессе пула) при мультипроцессном режиме (вижу его в коде) используют метод apply_async.

Советую посмотреть на примеры применения по поиску "apply_async" в документации:
https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20pool#module-multiprocessing.pool

Comment: Автор и так путает мультипроцессность с многопоточностью, а вы ещё асинхронность ему добавляете, он так совсем запутается ))